# JSOM, Rest API on-premise

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a virtual machine with SP2013 . How to find examples/work with JSOM , Rest API's on premise . Also If anyone can provide explanation on JSOM,CSOM,SSOM,REST,oauth it would be great . I want to know if i can use all the above OM on premise or if i can use all above OM on cloud ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Client Object Model (CSOM/JSOM) and the REST API work the same whether you are targeting an on-premises farm or an Office 365 tenant. The only real difference is how you authenticate but, once you are authenticated, the remainder of the code is the same.

I recently did a workshop at a conference that was an introduction to the Client Object Model and the REST API. The slides and demos can be downloaded from my SkyDrive.

https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=B810A8A4579BD670&id=B810A8A4579BD670%21758

There are some examples on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912(v=office.15).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022(v=office.15).aspx

I also have a course on Pluralsight that covers development with the Client Object Model and the REST API. You can get a free trial on the website if you are not already a member.

http://pluralsight.com/courses/sharepoint-2013-client-object-model-rest